# Putting XML elements in JTable

Tags: java, xml, swing, jtable, sax

I am trying to parse an XML file with sax parser in Java and then fill a `JTable` with the XML elements. The parsing is well done, the `JTable` is created, but the problem is that all the elements are placed in the same row and the same row is repeated.

Here is my code :

```
package read;

//import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class Read {

    public static Vector<Vector> rowData = new Vector<Vector>();
    public static Vector<String> rowOne = new Vector<String>();

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        try {
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
            DefaultHandler handler;
            handler = new DefaultHandler() {
                // private List<Personne> satff;
                boolean bstaff = false;
                boolean bfname = false;
                boolean blname = false;
                boolean bnname = false;
                boolean bsalary = false;
                private int i;

                public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String
                    qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
                    System.out.println("Start Element :" + qName);
                    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("staff")) {
                        bstaff = true;
                    }
                    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("FIRSTNAME")) {
                        bfname = true;
                    }
                    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("LASTNAME")) {
                        blname = true;
                    }
                    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("NICKNAME")) {
                        bnname = true;
                    }
                    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("SALARY")) {
                        bsalary = true;
                    }
                }

                public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
                    String qName) throws SAXException {
                    System.out.println("End Element :" + qName);
                    if ("staff".equals(qName)) {
                        rowData.addElement(rowOne);
                    };
                }

                @Override
                public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
                    if (bfname) {
                        String s = new String(ch, start, length);
                        rowOne.addElement(s);
                        System.out.println("First Name : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                        bfname = false;
                    }
                    if (blname) {
                        rowOne.addElement(new String(ch, start, length));
                        System.out.println("Last Name : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                        blname = false;
                    }
                    if (bnname) {
                        rowOne.addElement(new String(ch, start, length));
                        System.out.println("Nick Name : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                        bnname = false;
                    }
                    if (bsalary) {
                        rowOne.addElement(new String(ch, start, length));
                        System.out.println("Salary : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                        //rowData.addElement(rowOne);
                        bsalary = false;
                    }
                    System.out.println("longueur" + rowOne.size());
                }
            };
            saxParser.parse("file.xml", handler);
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
            columnNames.addElement("firstname");
            columnNames.addElement("lastname");
            columnNames.addElement("nickname");
            columnNames.addElement("salary");
            columnNames.addElement(" ");
            columnNames.addElement(" ");
            columnNames.addElement(" ");
            columnNames.addElement(" ");
            JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
            frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.setSize(300, 150);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My original XML file is the folowing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<company>
<staff >
<firstname>yong</firstname>
<lastname>mook kim</lastname>
<nickname>mkyong</nickname>
<salary>100000</salary>
</staff>
<staff >
<firstname>low</firstname>
<lastname>yin fong</lastname>
<nickname>fong fong</nickname>
<salary>200000</salary>
</staff>
</company>
```

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow! 2) `![enter image description here][1]`  Something went wrong there.  If you have a relevant screen-shot, upload it to an image share sites and link to it.

Comment: I could not find your image link.

Answer (score 2):

In your `startElement` method, change to this:

```
if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("staff"))
{
    rowOne = new Vector<String>();  
    bstaff = true;
}
```

The other `if` statements remain unchanged. Each `staff` element is put in a `Vector`.